# Чтение и запись в файл в pascal

Tags: pascal, файлы

Здравствуйте. Я тут впервые, поэтому если что не так, поправьте.

Как можно реализовать чтение из файла, если не известен формат записи данных, т.е не понятно как они там написаны. К примеру есть файл, в нем матрица

22 33

44 55

как её можно прочитать, чтобы сохранить формат записи, и записать это в новый файл.
Если можно, с примером подобной программы.

Благодарю за ответ.

**Дополнено.**

Ну я спросила возможности... Кусок кода я могу дать, но он ровным счетом ничего не даст, я просто не знаю как делать, поэтому и спросила.

```
//считывание
reset(f);
for i := 1 to n do
for j := 1 to n do
    read(f,x[i,j]);
close(f);
writeln ('матрица, считанная из файла');
for i := 1 to n do
    begin
         for j := 1 to n do
             write(x[i,j]:7:2);
         writeln;
    end;
```

Comment: Эм, вам нужно пример копирования файла ?

Comment: Нет нет, нужно использовать эту информацию, конечно модифицировать и записать новую в новый (ну или прежний) файл.

Т.е Просто использовать данные для работы

Comment: Обычно, вы делаете, у вас что-то не получается - мы подсказываем. Иначе вопрос рискует быть закрытым.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: Если формат записи неизвестен, то ничего никак не получится.

Comment: 2 mikillskegg

А методом исключения? Т.е проверяя строки? Если есть строка, то она пишется и +1 к счетчику строки... Ну или хотя-бы дайте пример для просто чтения с известными параметрами файла, а я поколдую уже

Answer (score 1):

Если запись в файл такая как вы сказали, а именно:

```
reset(f);
for i := 1 to n do
begin
  for j := 1 to n do
    write(f, x[i,j]:7:2);
  writeln(f);
end;
close(f);
```

То считывание должно быть таким:

```
reset(f);
for i := 1 to n do
begin
  for j := 1 to n do
    read(f, x[i,j]);
  readln(f);  
end;
close(f);
```